# SQL how to display results only if two parts are unique

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm currently having an issue trying to make a query such that it displays the fields only if both parts are unique. For example, lets say the fields to be displayed currently are as goes:

```
SELECT
Name,
CompanyName,
JobStartDate,
Birthday,
Age,
Favorite Ice Cream,
Height
From 'sample_person_data'
```

How would I set this so that it only displays fields where both CompanyName and JobStartDate are both distinct?

At first, I thought just putting distinct would be enough, but came to the realization that would not work, I then thought what if I make it so that it has to check both CompanyName + JobStartDate as unique fields, so only showing the fields where both those two things are unique, but could not go about implementing it.

Essentially what I'm aiming to achieve is if there was a large dataset with some repeated values, how could I help display only the unique fields. I use CompanyName and JobStartDate as examples here, but I understand that people can start at the same company on the same day, therefore this would be a concept which could expand into adding more comparisons.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: Based on comments I am trying to provide further detail by example
Say this is the sample data:

| Name | CompanyName | JobStartDate | Birthday | Age | Favorite Ice Cream | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Google | 04-17-00 | 01-01-78 | 50 | Vanilla | 5-7 |
| John | Google | 04-17-00 | 01-01-78 | 50 | Chocolate | 5-7 |
| John | Microsoft | 04-17-00 | 02-01-95 | 30 | Chocolate | 5-8 |
| Nancy | Google | 06-27-00 | 04-01-78 | 50 | Vanilla | 5-2 |
| Joanna | Google | 08-19-00 | 05-01-78 | 50 | Vanilla | 5-0 |

So here we see the same John from Google filled the form twice because say he decided to change his favorite ice cream. How do I edit the query such that it displays such as the following:

| Name | CompanyName | JobStartDate | Birthday | Age | Favorite Ice Cream | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Google | 04-17-00 | 01-01-78 | 50 | Vanilla | 5-7 |
| John | Microsoft | 04-17-00 | 02-01-95 | 30 | Chocolate | 5-8 |
| Nancy | Google | 06-27-00 | 04-01-78 | 50 | Vanilla | 5-2 |
| Joanna | Google | 08-19-00 | 05-01-78 | 50 | Vanilla | 5-0 |

I don't really care if his favorite ice cream shows up as Chocolate or Vanilla, but rather that only 1 entry of a John from google shows up, using the current company + job start date as the identifying fields for example.

Comment: First thing first, please tag your question with whatever DBMS you are using like `mysql` `oracke` `sqlserver` etc. Moreover, go thru `window functions` `row_number` in SQL with which you can get desired results.

Comment: @Gobby89 The wording in this question is confusing. What do you mean by "unique" and "distinct" and such? Please edit the question to be clearer and we can help you. :)

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. It seems the solution is simple, but I can't understand the question well.

Comment: I have updated the post, I hope this has made it more clear @JohnK.

Comment: I have updated the post, I hope this has made it more clear @TheImpaler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below simple approach

```
select * from your_table
qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by CompanyName, JobStartDate)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: glad it worked for you :o)